# Round button with text and icon in flutter

Tags: icons, flutter

how to have a button with text and icon for the `flutter`?

I wanted to have a `button` which looks like icon with a text that is able to put at the bottom of the screen

For example, the icon is like at here: [android-button-with-icon-and-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csw8G.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 219, accepted):

**EDIT 1:** With Flutter 1.20 release Flutter Team did breaking changes introducing new buttons. So the below mentioned button types are deprecated. Use [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) instead of [FlatButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) and [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) instead of [RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html).

```
TextButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
```

*See breaking changes for buttons and their themes [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons)*

**Note: FlatButton and RaisedButton is DEPRECATED**

You can simply use named constructors for creating different types of buttons with icons. For instance

```
FlatButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
```

But if you have specfic requirements then you can always create custom button with different layouts or simply wrap a widget in [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Comment: Can we do this postfix Icon with lable ?

Comment: Because icon and label are just widgets, you can switch icon and label to move the icon to the right: RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: Text('Button'), label: Icon(Icons.cached)),

Comment: And what about moving the icon to the top or bottom?

Comment: To customize this we can refer to the source code of TextButton.icon(), specifically the build function at line 462 of text_button.dart

Comment: `ElevatedButton.icon` instead of `Elevated.icon`

Answer (score 64):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

```
SizedBox.fromSize(
  size: Size(56, 56), // button width and height
  child: ClipOval(
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.orange, // button color
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
        onTap: () {}, // button pressed
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.call), // icon
            Text("Call"), // text
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 54):

You can achieve that by using a `FlatButton` that contains a `Column` (for showing a text below the icon) or a `Row` (for text next to the icon), and then having an `Icon` Widget and a `Text` widget as children.

Here's an example:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hello world"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                color: Colors.orange,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.add),
                    Text("Add")
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => {},
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
}
```

This will produce the following:

[image: Result]

Comment: FlatButton id deprecated now.

Answer (score 24):

Use Column or Row in a Button child, Row for horizontal button, Column for vertical, and dont forget to *contain* it with the size you need:

```
Container(
  width: 120.0,
  height: 30.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    color: Color(0XFFFF0000),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Play this song', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white,),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Adding a new Row in the RaisedButton is a right solution for placing text and an icon together.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Using the `.icon()` constructors places too many constraints on the layout when trying to achieve a custom layout.

Comment: It is Deprecated

Answer (score 17):

If you need a button like this:

[image]

You can use `RaisedButton` and use the child property to do this. You need to add a Row and inside row you can add a `Text` widget and an `Icon` Widget to achieve this. If you want to use png image, you can use similar widget to achieve this.

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
          0,
          SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
          0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Continue',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward,
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 15):

The way i usually do it is by embedding a Row inside the Raised button:

```
class Sendbutton extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.black,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Send'),
              Icon(Icons.send)
            ],
          ),

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: RaisedButton is deprecated. Use ElevatedButton instead.

Answer (score 12):

The FlatButton, RaisedButton and OutlineButton widgets have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

Just put this code below as Button. Also the accepted answer is updated in September, 2021.

```
TextButton.icon(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
      ), 
    ),
    onPressed: () => {},
    icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded,),
    label: Text('Contact me',),
  ),
```

[image: This button is white with blue text ignore the yellow part it's just the page's background]

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like,

```
RaisedButton.icon( elevation: 4.0,
                    icon: Image.asset('images/image_upload.png' ,width: 20,height: 20,) ,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    onPressed: getImage,
                    label: Text("Add Team Image",style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0))
                  ),
```

Answer (score 9):

I hope this will help out. I am using flutter 2.10.1

[image]

```
ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
```

**How to use ElevatedButton.icon**

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.add_circle,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        label: Text(
          "Schedule",
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 133, 194),
          fixedSize: const Size(208, 43),
        ),
      )
```

You can read the documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html

Comment: is there any provision to use icon @ right Instead of Left Align?

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to the previous answers... But I realised if the icons are in a row (say three icons as represented in the image above), you need to play around with columns and rows.

Here is the code

```
 Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.call,
                      )),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.message,
                      )),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.block,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    '   Call',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Message',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Block',
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oY3Z.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

In the Newest Version of Flutter, I think you can use Just IconButton Widget like this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      Text('Volume')
    ],
  );
}
```

Hope this helps out, learn more about it from this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html).

Answer (score 2):

If You need the text to be centered, and the image to be besides it, like this:
[image: Flutter RaisedButton with image and centered text]

Then You can achieve it with this widget tree:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: Text(
        'Push it! '*10,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),),
      Image.network(
        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[Full example available on my dartpad.dev (link).](https://dartpad.dev/e85a800a06a2bcb4ad28ea27054d19b7)

Answer (score 1):

**Flutter 2.4:**

The best recommended way is using **ShapeDecoration**

Here is a example  using an Inkwell (simulating a button, but you can use a button instead and get same result).

```
InkWell(          
      onTap: (){},
      child: Container(        
               width: 50,
               height: 50,
               decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                             shape: CircleBorder(), //here we set the circular figure
                             color: Colors.red
                           ),
                         child: Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                     Icons.email,
                                     size: 30,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                            ),
                        )
)
```

These are the posibles shapes in  ShapeDecoration:

```
RoundedRectangleBorder(),
BeveledRectangleBorder(),
ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
CircleBorder(),
```

link example of result: https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/140138/isolated/preview/88e50689fa3280c748d000aaf0bad480-icono-de-ronda-de-correo-electronico-1.png

Answer (score 1):

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: const Icon(
    Icons.add_circle,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  onPressed: onPressed,
  label: Text(
    "Button",
    style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.green),
  ),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 186, 239),
    fixedSize: const Size(210, 45),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Elegant & simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
       TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                primary: Colors.black,

                //backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                onSurface: Colors.grey,
                minimumSize:
                    Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20, 40)),
            onPressed: () => null,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: new Text("b )",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      )),
                ),
                Image.network(
                    'https://blabala7710263543.jpg'),
              ],
            )),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

as of flutter 3.3.10
you can achieve this button using Container, Column and InkWell

Like:

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () {/*DO SOMETHING*/},
              child: Container(
                  height: 100,//PREF HEIGHT
                  width: 100, //PREF WIDTH
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.orange, //YOUR BUTTON COLOR
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [Icon(Icons.add, size:18 /*PREF ICON SIZE*/),SizedBox(height:25), Text('MY BUTTON')]))),
```

Just use Row and Column combination to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Resizable custom button widget with an icon.

[image]

*menu_button.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final IconData iconData;
  const MenuButton(
      {required this.text,
      this.onPressed,
      this.width = 200,
      this.height = 60,
      super.key,
      required this.iconData});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Icon(iconData),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(text),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Call like this:

```
 ...
MenuButton(
            text: 'О ПРИЛОЖЕНИИ',
            onPressed: () => context.push("/menu/about_app"),
            width: 280,
            iconData: Icons.info_outlined),
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tty this if you also want to have a full-width button with icon and text:

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextButton(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Some Text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  ],
                ),
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                  iconColor: Colors.blue,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
```