# Flutter button with icon and text looks odd

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a Flutter app that has a button with a text and icon as label, the icon being placed right of the text. The approach described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442247/round-button-with-text-and-icon-in-flutter) yields an odd looking button that seems expanded to the width of the app, see this image (link as I am not allowed to attach images):

[Button becomes wide when adding a Row widget as child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46eUH.png)

It is not clear to me which layout widgets to use to tweak the text+image button to be formatted as the plain text button.

The code for producing the above example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Button with text and icon!"),
                  new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              child: new Text("Button with only text")
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Row property ***`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`*** does the trick here.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text('Button with text and icon!'),
                  new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: new Text('Button with only text'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use this [`RaisedButton.icon`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.icon.html)

Simple Usage:

```
RaisedButton.icon(
   onPressed: () {},
   elevation: 2.0,
   shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
   ),
   color: const Color(0xFFFFB822),
   icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
   label: Text("Add to Cart",
             style: TextStyle(
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: How can you add padding or make the height bigger for `RaisedButton.icon`?

Comment: how can I add a custom icon? Let's say the icon I want does not exist in any of the packages, how do I add add my own?

Comment: @Suren you should check fluttericon.com

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple and Easy...

```
ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.green, elevation: 2),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text('Edit'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

you can change your icon or text color, whatever you want to.
Hope this'll help you.